# Exception trace in Firefox console not using source maps

Tags: angular, typescript, firefox, source-maps

I have an Angular / TS project with the following **tsconfig.json** file:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

In case of an exception in my code, the trace is written in the web explorer dev tool console.

I can add breakpoints in my TS files in *Firefox* and *Chrome*.

**Problem :**

With *Chrome* everything's OK. The trace describe the error and send me to the right file.

But with *Firefox*, the trace doesn't link me to the TS file, but the polyfills.bundle.js instead.

```
ERROR Error: "[object Object]"
resolvePromisehttp://localhost/app/polyfills.bundle.js:6856:31resolvePromisehttp://localhost/app/polyfills.bundle.js:6813:17scheduleResolveOrRejecthttp://localhost/app/polyfills.bundle.js:6915:17invokeTaskhttp://localhost/app/polyfills.bundle.js:6463:17onInvokeTaskhttp://localhost/app/vendor.bundle.js:68464:24invokeTaskhttp://localhost/app/polyfills.bundle.js:6462:17runTaskhttp://localhost/app/polyfills.bundle.js:6230:28drainMicroTaskQueuehttp://localhost/app/polyfills.bundle.js:6637:25invokeTaskhttp://localhost/app/polyfills.bundle.js:6542:21invokeTaskhttp://localhost/app/polyfills.bundle.js:7582:9globalZoneAwareCallbackhttp://localhost/app/polyfills.bundle.js:7608:17
```

The *Firefox* property **devtools.source-map.locations.enabled** is set to **true**.

Any help would be appreciated.